# Always getting an error every installing expo-cli

Tags: sudo, 19.04, npm

So, basically, I always get an error every installing expo-cli through an npm or yarn, I wonder how to fix this error, Thank You.

Using NPM :

```
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.

> @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.4 preinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux
> node platform.js

/usr/bin/expo-cli -> /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/usr/bin/expo -> /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js

> iltorb@2.4.3 install /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

info looking for cached prebuild @ /home/ouka/.npm/_prebuilds/105edd-iltorb-v2.4.3-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz
http request GET https://github.com/MayhemYDG/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.3/iltorb-v2.4.3-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz
http 200 https://github.com/MayhemYDG/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.3/iltorb-v2.4.3-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz
info downloading to @ /home/ouka/.npm/_prebuilds/105edd-iltorb-v2.4.3-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz.19644-9030303840b2.tmp
info renaming to @ /home/ouka/.npm/_prebuilds/105edd-iltorb-v2.4.3-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz
info unpacking @ /home/ouka/.npm/_prebuilds/105edd-iltorb-v2.4.3-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz
WARN install EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb/build'
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/ouka/.node-gyp/11.15.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-15-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> sharp@0.22.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.4/libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
ERR! sharp EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/sharp/19673-libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz'
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/ouka/.node-gyp/11.15.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/sharp/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/sharp/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-15-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN @expo/dev-tools@0.5.17 requires a peer of @expo/xdl@^53.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.4 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iltorb@2.4.3 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iltorb@2.4.3 install: `node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.22.1 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.22.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ouka/.npm/_logs/2019-06-02T22_37_05_036Z-debug.log
```

Using yarn :

```
 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "expo-cli > @expo/dev-tools@0.5.17" has incorrect peer dependency "@expo/xdl@^53.8.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/5] ⢀ waiting...
[-/5] ⢀ waiting...
[-/5] ⢀ waiting...
[4/5] ⢀ sharp
error /home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp
Output:
info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.4/libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
fs.js:119
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/tmp/25010-libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz' -> '/home/ouka/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    at copyFileSync (fs.js:1743:3)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js:100:13)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at fs.close (internal/fs/streams.js:209:14)
    at FSReqCallback.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:145:20)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@11.15.0 | linux | x64
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/node-v11.15.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/node-v11.15.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/ouka/.node-gyp/11.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/ouka/.node-gyp/11.15.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/ouka/.node-gyp/11.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp/build'
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
../src/common.cc:25:10: fatal error: vips/vips8: No such file or directory
 #include <vips/vips8>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sharp.target.mk:128: Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:255:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-15-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ouka/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install it with `sudo` access, just like

```
sudo npm install -g expo-cli
```

or

```
sudo yarn global add expo-cli
```